# News feed with nice transitions using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I´m trying to create a box that displays news feed.

Here´s what I have done so far
http://jsfiddle.net/KXdyU/40/

I don´t want it to jump. I want the last row to fade out as the ul moves down to let a new li fade in.

Could I get some help with this please?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/KXdyU/41/) you are, hope this is what you asked for!